# FireBase Sync with Android Studio failed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, firebase

I try implementing an app that put details about you in database in ***Firebase***.

I do the sync with the code from the website from [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup)
Android Studio Version: 3.0.1
The Code is from [THIS](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-firebase-tutorial-1/)

build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        //you need to add this line
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0' // google-services plugin
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com" // Google's Maven repository
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle in the app:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.eranp.clientpage"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation files('libs/activation.jar')
    implementation files('libs/additionnal.jar')
    implementation files('libs/mail.jar')
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The error output:

```
 Error:Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0. Searched
in the following locations:
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/google-services/3.2.0/google-services-3.2.0.pom
    file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/google/gms/google-services/3.2.0/google-services-3.2.0.jar
Required by:
    project :
```

What do I need to do to fix that?

Comment: First of all remove the } sign after the apply plugin. It doesn't need the braces. 
Then try

Comment: dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
}
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: I am completely unable to reproduce this error.  Is there something you're not showing?  Please try a new, fresh project.

Comment: This is  a new project

Comment: show your complete complete dependency

Comment: now I edited all the dependency

Comment: download google-services-3.2.0.pom and google-services-3.2.0.jar and add them at the location specified in the error

Comment: from where can I download? because if I goolge it there is no option to download the files

Comment: https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/3.2.0#files/com%2Fgoogle%2Fgms%2Fgoogle-services%2F3.2.0 go to files>3.2.0

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I also had problems with syncing gradle with firebase, I played around with the versions until it worked.